# reverse Geolocation : Postal Code Issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

This code I am using to get the entire Address of the user using Reverse Geolocation. Can someone suggest me the way to just get the Postal Code or Zip code out of it .

```
//Geocoding Block
[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler:
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

     //Get nearby address
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];


     //String to hold address
     NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];


     //Print the location to console
     NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);

     //Set the label text to current location
     [locationLabel setText:locatedAt];

 }];
```

Comment: have you checked what's inside `placemark.addressDictionary`? I'd imagine there is a key for zipcode.

Comment: there is a  documents present for this on Apple Dev http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html , can but i lacks proper documentation . its is suppose to be placemark.postalCode....

Comment: iOSRider has an answer in this question which shows how to get the Zip / Post Code: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5058798/558933

Comment: @RoboticCat is it necessary to cast it?

Comment: not sure ? and the above link is not working fine .

Answer (score 0):

Use google maps to convert the geo location to a zip adress.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: google Maps are Depreciate from IOS , Google released its Maps Sdk today