# Which App Store, the user is logged into

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to detect which App Store (US, German, UK, France...etc) the user is logged into on his device?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get device location (only country) in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534496/get-device-location-only-country-in-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this snippet of code you can determinethe users country. So that means that in most cases the store is also set to the country they live in.

```
- (NSString *)getUserCountry {
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    return [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
}
```

For example this can return `the Netherlands` or `England` if you live in the Netherlands or England,