# How to detect that my phone is in China network?

Tags: android, ios, ip-geolocation

I am creating a global app (for android and ios) that needs to show a different screen in case the smartphone is in a Chinese network. Device can have a sim card or not (WiFi only) so it is not 100% sure to get Mobile country code info from cellular network.

I though in "ping" sites that I know are blocked in china (like facebook.com),to discover if I am in china or not but this approach seems to be a kind of fragile.

Finally I thought in compare my phone's IP against the list of Chinese IPs. Is there a list of reliable Chinese IPs (like a range of IPs for china)?

Is there a reliable mechanism to detect if my device is in China or not?

Comment: "iOS Check country" - https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ios%20check%20country

Comment: CLLocationManager and reverse geocoding

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8534623/6611229

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get device location (only country) in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534496/get-device-location-only-country-in-ios)

Comment: i want to avoid geolocation google api since it has limits per day (need to pay for more limits)