# convert Nsurl Domain to my country domain

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

how to convert Nsurl Domain to my country domain

Example :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

How can get some thing like http://www.google.com***.eg***

it can detect my zone and change it with my domain zone, if website support multi zones domain.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a path in the url just append .eg to the end of the string.

```
NSString *newCountryString = [[url absoluteString] stringByAppendingString:@".eg"];

NSURL *newCountryUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:newCountryString];
```

If the url has a path do this:

```
NSString *host = [url host];
NSString *domain = [[host componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject];
NSString *newCountryString = [[url absoluteString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:domain withString:[domain stringByAppendingString:@".eg"]];
NSURL *newCountryUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:newCountryString];
```

Comment: i don't want to add "eg" specific  i want to add any zone like "uk,..."

Comment: eg was just an example. If you want to get location by language settings use:    NSString *countryCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];    if you want by physical location check this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534496/get-device-location-only-country-in-ios