# How to detect is user's (iOS device) is in Europe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

If say user has not given me location permission then how can I detect that the user is in Europe?

Comment: use locale......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get device location (only country) in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534496/get-device-location-only-country-in-ios)

Comment: This is not a dupe of that post. Poster here has specifically said they have no location permission, other post does. I have the same issue, this is probably GDPR related.

Comment: yes its GDPR related

Answer (score 1):

May this help you:

Use current `TimeZone` (or try Locale). It will give (near by) time zone, set by user for its device date-time.

**Objective C:**

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSString *timeZoneName = [timeZone name];
NSLog(@"timeZoneName - %@",timeZoneName);

NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSLog(@"countryCode - %@",countryCode);
```

**Swift 4:**

```
let name = TimeZone.current
print("TimeZone name -  \(name)")
// TimeZone name - Asia/Kolkata (current)

let currentlocale = Locale.current
print("currentlocale - \(currentlocale)")
// currentlocale - en_IN (current)

let regioncode = Locale(identifier: currentlocale.regionCode!)    
print("regioncode - \(regioncode)")
// regioncode - in (fixed)
```

Comment: TimeZone or Locale depend only on device's settings, not physical location. Since OP mentioned trying to use location, my guess is he wants the latter.

Comment: @mag_zbc -  I know that. But as per my knowledge this is the possible 
(near by) answer. There is may not be exact solution for this question because of location permission (or I may be wrong). But to help OP I just posted near by answer. May it can be useful to find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Checking `Locale` will not do you much good, because it reflects only your device's setting, not physical location.

If you have been denied location service, I think the best workaround would be to use a free IP-based geolocation service, like [this one](http://ip-api.com/docs/).

All you need to do is perform a `GET` request to `http://ip-api.com/json/{ipAddress}`

Example:

`GET http://ip-api.com/json/8.8.8.8` (google-public-dns-a.google.com) returns a `json`

```
{
    "as": "AS15169 Google LLC",
    "city": "Mountain View",
    "country": "United States",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "isp": "Google",
    "lat": 37.4229,
    "lon": -122.085,
    "org": "Google",
    "query": "8.8.8.8",
    "region": "CA",
    "regionName": "California",
    "status": "success",
    "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "zip": ""
}
```

As you can see, it returns you a bunch of useful information, like country name or country code.

You can easily find how to get device's IP address in Objective-c, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-osx-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically)

The downside is that you will not get accurate result if the user is connected to internet via VPN.

Comment: GDPR - I cannot get IP of user without his consent. And to show consent dialog I need to detect if he is in Europe. :)

Comment: According to documentation, you don't need to specify IP - _You can supply an IP address or domain to lookup, or none to use your current IP address._