# Get location updates in background - only for Country change iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, background-mode

What is the best way in core location to get background location updates only when there is change in country?

Comment: You can create the country's geofencing area and catch it in `didEnterRegion`

Comment: It can be any country, how do I achieve in this case?

Comment: If you has no data about it, I think you can only check the country every the locationmanager update the new location data.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534496/get-device-location-only-country-in-ios.

Comment: see this for step by step tutorial : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reverseGeocodeLocation` of the `CLGeocoder` to get the current country for your location.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations objects: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = objects.last!
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location!) { (places, error) in
            if(error == nil){
                if(places != nil){
                    let place: CLPlacemark = places![0]
                    let country = place.country
                    // do something if its changed

                }
            } else {
                //handle error
            }
```

But the issue will be you need to be monitoring location for this to happen. You can use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` as one option or you could set desired accuracy to something big like `kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers` both of which will reduce the amount of power used by location updates.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **geofencing**, there are great articles about it. Any way you'll need to implement functions like

`func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)` (CLLocationManagerDelegate)

`func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion)` (CLLocationManagerDelegate)

`open func requestAlwaysAuthorization()` (CLLocationManager)

`func startMonitoring(for region: CLRegion)` (CLLocationManager)