# What is the best way to retrieve the user's Country or Region from their GameCenter account?

Tags: ios, game-center, account

What is the best way to retrieve the user's Country or Region from their GameCenter account? Is this information exposed in the Apple APIs?

Comment: please, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534623/1040347

Answer (score 0):

A locale is a user's region setting on their device, and you can read it without asking for permission. If we're just going to ask what country the user is in:

let locale = Locale.current.regionCode